# Mandrill.Net Adding Multiple Attachments

Tags: email, mandrill

I am trying to send an email via Mandrill.Net, and am getting stuck trying to add multiple attachments.  I have got the following code that create the list of attachments as `IEnumerable`, but I am getting the error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mandrill.Models.Attachment]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mandrill.Models.EmailAttachment]'.
```

The code is below:

```
                try
                {
                    EmailService ems = new EmailService();
                    EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage();
                    List<EmailAddress> ToAdd = new List<EmailAddress>();
                    EmailAddress MainTo = new EmailAddress();
                    MainTo.Email = qe.ToAddress;
                    MainTo.Type = "bcc";
                    ToAdd.Add(MainTo);
                    msg.FromEmail = qe.FromAddress;
                    msg.FromName = qe.FromName;
                    msg.AddHeader("Reply-To", qe.ReplyTo);
                    msg.To = ToAdd;
                    msg.Subject = qe.Subject;
                    msg.Html = qe.Body;
                    msg.TrackClicks = true;
                    msg.TrackOpens = true;
                    //  Need to add in Email Attachments
                    List<EmailAttachment> lea = new QueuedEmailModels().GetEmailAttachmentsByQueuedEmailID(qe.QueuedEmailsID); // Gets List of Attachments in DB
                    List<Attachment> lma = new List<Attachment>();

                    foreach(BRPA.EmailAttachment ea in lea)
                    {

                        byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + ea.AttachmentID));
                        Attachment at = new Attachment
                        {
                            Content = Convert.ToBase64String(array),
                            Name = ea.AttachmentName,
                            Type = ""
                        };
                        lma.Add(at);

                    }
                    msg.Attachments = (IEnumerable<Mandrill.Models.EmailAttachment>)lma.AsEnumerable();

                    //  End of Attachments
                    await ems.SendMailviaMandrill(msg);

                    qe.Status = "Sent";
                    qe.DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
                    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
```

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Oops - Found the answer.

I had a class for `EmailAttachment` that was overriding the `Mandrill.Models.EmailAttachment`.

Specified the full name and all is good.

Comment: Hi, are you using web api, are you declaring the singleton ?  If you are using the singleton, could you share how how declared it in the controller where is used?  Thanks